# Flow Router, Component Will not Render

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  action() {
    ReactLayout.render(App, {content: <LP />});
  }
});
```

I followed https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/rendering-react-components guide for using Flow Router. However, I keep getting this error:

I don't understand why there is an unexpected token. Does anyone know?

```
/Users/GLu/Desktop/more2me/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/lib/router.js:11
    ReactLayout.render(App, { content: <LP /> });                      // 3
                                       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at /Users/GLu/Desktop/more2me/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:241:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/GLu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/GLu/Desktop/more2me/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

Thanks so much in advance for any help.

Comment: Ok, my answer was premature. I've never used Meteor or JSX (didn't even know about it until now, honestly). The error suggests that your javascript interpreter is seeing that naked `<LP />` - so I guess JSX isn't being applied to your file before it gets handed off to the JS interpreter?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use JSX in a JS file.  Try changing the filename from `router.js` to `router.jsx`.

Comment: thanks, that did it!